# Vlookup not working across sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

My intention is to lookup value in Date column in sheet 1, find matching date column in Sheet 2 then copy the date from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1.

Formula I am Using is --

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,2!A2:C3,1,FALSE)
```

but the result errors out in N?A value. Not sure what am I doing wrong?

1

```
+--------+--------+
| Date   | Value  | 
+--------+--------+
|28/02/18|        | 
+--------+--------+

2
+--------+--------+---------------+
| Value  | %      |Date           | 
+--------+--------+---------------+
| 1000000| 20     |   28/02/18    |
+--------+--------+---------------+
| 2000000| 10     |   31/01/18    |
+--------+--------+---------------+
| 3000000| 30     |   29/12/17    |
+--------+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLOOKUP requires that the lookup column be on the left.  Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=INDEX(2!A:A,MATCH(A2,2!C:C,0))
```